# navbar toggler click function is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hey guys so I'm trying to make a fullscreen navigation bar with vertically and horizontally centered content, I achieved my goal and created everything easily, but there's one problem.. I wrote all the code but it seems that the jquery code is not working, I checked with chrome's developers tool and there's no class added to the tag that I want it to be added to. Here's my code

```
<div class="toggle"><a><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Students</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Other
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-down" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="comingsoon.html">States</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="memes/memes.html">Memes</a>
                </div>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
.toggle {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.toggle a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #262626;
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: .5s;
}
.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}
.menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
.menu ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family:;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #262626;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu.active {
    left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```
<script type="text-javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.toggle a').click(function() {
                   $('.menu').toggleClass('active');
                })
            })
</script>
```

Comment: Your JS code is perfect. Make sure you have added the jQuery library before the JS code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is fine, you need to replace only "text-javascript" to "text/javascript"

Comment: OH MY GOD.. How did I not notice it, I've never done such mistake... Thank you so much it works now.